# Passing a time zone into a web api call from moment with nodatime

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, nodatime

I'm about to go insane dealing with datetime issues and the web.

I have a web server hosted in the Central Time Zone.  When clients in the Eastern Time Zone try and schedule an item for a given day using my app, they pass in the value of (for example) 3/14/2015.  When we pass the code back to our model, which is sent to the web api, we persist is using something like the code below.

```
moment.utc($("#mydatepicker").val).hour(0).minute(0).second(0)).toISOString();
```

This results in a string like the following:

```
2015-03-14T04:00:00.000Z
```

When the item is converted back on the server in web api, it converts to

```
3/13/2015 11:00:00 PM
```

Logic then strips off time and you can see what happens from here.  Since I stripped off the time, it is now the day prior and that is the value persisted to the database.

I need to know some way to send a value from moment, into the web api preferrably as a ZonedDateTime in the client's time zone.  I can then convert it to UTC for persistance in the DB.

I've seen things about using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet, but I am unclear on how to to use it with Moment and pass it back and forth across web api/ajax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to know some way to send a value from moment, into the web api preferrably as a ZonedDateTime in the client's time zone. I can then convert it to UTC for persistance in the DB.

If that's what you want, then:

- In your moment.js code, use `.format()` instead of `.toISOString()`, which will still give you an ISO8601 string, but will include the local offset instead of setting it to UTC.
- In your ASP.Net code, define your values as a `DateTimeOffset` (or a noda `OffsetDateTime`) rather than a `DateTime`.

***However***, I don't think that's really what you want.  When it comes to dates and times, *context* is super important.  Here, you said you were picking a date from a date picker.  When you do that - what time is being chosen by the user?  In most cases, they *aren't* choosing a time - they're just picking a date.  But since the JavaScript `Date` object is really a "date + time" object, it assigns midnight as a default time.  Moment is no better in this regard.

Really, converting to UTC doesn't make logical sense when you are just talking about a calendar date.  The string value you *probably* should be sending across the wire should just be a whole date, as in `"2015-03-14"`.  My guess is that is what you are starting with anyway.  If not, then do `moment.utc(yourvalue).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` to get it.  (Using UTC here is just a way to avoid local time zone issues, like midnight not existing in Brazil on the spring-forward day.)

This corresponds to the NodaTime `LocalDate` type in your .NET code.  If you weren't using Noda Time, you would define the type as a `DateTime` and just ignore the time portion.  In your database, if there's a date-only type available, then use it.  For example, SQL Server has a `date` type.

I'd also encourage you to watch my Pluralsight course, [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals) - which covers many of these issues.

Regarding using `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` in WebAPI (so you can use `LocalDate` directly), in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file, wire it up like so:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
                 .ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

Then it should just work.

Comment: That seemed to work.  I changed the date result to a date string and all seems to work. I'm still doing some logic server side, but everything seems ok.  I'm doing additional logic to make sure I save values in my franchise's time (their TZ is kept in the DB) then converted to UTC for DB storage.  I have to train my users that if you set a value to Midnight franch. time and they are an hour ahead of you, when you view the result locally, moment is going to show it in your local time so it's going to be one hour less than it is for the franch.  Makes me crosseyed.  Will check out the course.

Comment: @Matt instead of moment.format can you not just preserve the offset by calling moment.toISOString(true)? It's possible this option was only added recently

Answer (score 1):

I would start by sending all dates and times to the server as UTC times.  If you store UTC times only then you should be able to show the correct time that something is scheduled on the client side.

When you create your moment on the client side, do you run it out .toDate() first before sending it to the server side?  What code are you running on the server side?  Is it a .Net WebApi?

Comment: The code you see above is exactly from my client side.  I am sending and receiving everything in utc format.  I am not doing the toDate though.  It is .NET WebApi on the server side.  What happens is that the time in UTC is set to midnight but the server sees it as one hour earlier (11 pm the previous day) because the client is in Eastern and the server is in Central.

Comment: OK I understand now.

On the client side, you should convert your moment().toDate() so that the serialized JSON you send to the server will have the correct format for your webapi.

On the server the same rule still stands, you must store in UTC in order for the client to pull the time and view it correctly.  It appears as if you are doing a local timezone conversion of the date before.  Does the server side DateTime show as a UTC date?

Comment: No.  On the server side, when the WebApi reads the variable (we are creating the object by using a `[FromBody]MyModel myModel` argument to the function) it creates it as a DateTimeKind.Local.  So Midnight Eastern time is seen as 11 pm previous when created as Local.  I see someone put code in changing it to Unspecified.  Maybe that is causing the issue.